# Compare user input values with values in database in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, controller

### Heading ##[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult LogIn(UserDetail user)
    {
        using (AdventureWorksDBEntities User = new AdventureWorksDBEntities())
        {
            var UserInput= User.UserDetails.Where(b => b.UserName == user.UserName && b.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            if (UserInput!=null)
            {
                Session["Id"] = UserInput.id.ToString();
                Session["UserName"] = UserInput.UserName.ToString();
                return Redirect("#");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("","Username or Password Doesn't Exist");
            }
        }
        return View();
```

I want to compare user input values with the values in the database.

Comment: So what is your question? What problems are you having?

Comment: In the if statement i have given if (UserInput!=null) i want to check the userinput username and password value with values already in the database

Comment: But you already have - the value of `UserInput` will be `null` if there is not a match

Comment: It is allowing any values rather than allowing only the values in the databse!!.. @StephenMuecke

Comment: No its not! Your `Where(b => b.UserName == user.UserName && b.Password == user.Password)` means that if there is not an exact match, it will return `null`. And as a side note, **NEVER** store passwords in a database as plain text (they need to be hashed - and I strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and learn about [security and authorization](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security))

Comment: But even if i give a random value it is redirected to the next page but i want to redirect to the next page only if the value matches

Comment: Then there is something wrong with you data.

Comment: Alright I couldnt able to find the mistake!.. Thanks for your time.